# Errors in Program which seem to be beyond my understanding

Tags: java

According to what I learn from the book of `java`, I attempted the exercise  from the same book using char and for loop.The exercise was about to get an output which is given below,

> A a
>   B b
>   ""
>   Z z

There should be space b/w upper and lower case.My program is given below,

```
public class Exercise_20 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char upperCase, lowerCase;
        int i;
        upperCase = A;
        lowerCase = a;

        for (i = 1 i <= 26; i++) {
            System.out.println(uppercase + "\t" + lowercase);
            uppercase++;
            lowercase++;
        }
    }
}
```

Since b/w A till Z are 26 letters that's why I put the maximum value of i =26.

Please let me know what is the problem with my program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should it not be **upperCase=   'A';** **lowerCase=   'a';** ? Also, the exact error messages you get would be helpful...

Comment: What is the error? Is it a compile error? Missing semicolon in the for loop expression?

Comment: Note that you have `upperCase` and `uppercase`. You should decide on how you want to write your variables.

Answer (score 2):

The char variables needs to be in single quotes; the for-loop is missing a semi-colon and you refer to the variables with different names - they need to be exactly the same:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    char upperCase, lowerCase;
    int i;
    upperCase = 'A';
    lowerCase = 'a';

    for (i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
        System.out.println(upperCase + "\t" + lowerCase);
        upperCase++;
        lowerCase++;
    }
}
```

[Working example in Ideone](http://ideone.com/0VHGJw)

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of syntax errors in your code. This produces the desired output:

```
public class Exercise_20 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char upperCase, lowerCase;
        int i;
        upperCase = 'A';
        lowerCase = 'a';

        for (i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
            System.out.println(upperCase + "\t" + lowerCase);
            upperCase++;
            lowerCase++;
        }
    }
}
```

1. You should declare chars enclosed in single quotes. E.g: `char a = 'a'`.
2. You declare the variables as `upperCase` and `lowerCase`, then reference them with `uppercase` and `lowercase`.
3. Missing semi colon in for loop.

Comment: Thanks  a lot guys especially Martin MJ. Your comments provide me a lot of help.Thanks again.